# cannot connect spring project with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu

I have mysql installed on my machine which using ubuntu 22.04 as OS (mysql verssion is : mysql  Ver 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))) , i have build a simple spring project and i want connected with mysql database, i have check all the credentials needed. This is the application.properties file

```
# Database configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stocky
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=

# Hibernate configuration
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

# Server configuration
server.port=8090

# Logging configuration
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
logging.level.com.example=DEBUG
```

and here is the error message:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I have check if the mysql is running, if the port is libre.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL specific `CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`, means that the DB isn't reachable at all. This can have one or more of the following causes:

- IP address or hostname in datasource URL is wrong. Try using the actual database server IP address instead of local host.
- Port number is missing or wrong in datasource URL.
- DB server is down.
- DB server doesn't accept TCP/IP connections.
- DB server has run out of connections.
- Something in between Spring and DB is blocking connections, e.g. a firewall or proxy.

To solve the one or the other, follow the following advices:

- Verify and test them with ping.
- Refresh DNS or use IP address in datasource URL instead.
- Verify it based on my.cnf of MySQL DB.
- Start the DB.
- Verify if mysqld is started without the --skip-networking option.
- Restart the DB and fix your code accordingly that it closes connections in finally.
- Disable firewall and/or configure firewall/proxy to allow/forward the port.

You can refer to a [similar question on SO and its answers for more on this.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2983248/9648404)

Comment: Please do not paraphrase an existing high-quality answer, flag this question as a duplicate of the target answer.